# How to iterate rank normalisation over all input variables in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to rank normalise all variables in pandas DataFrame to range [0,1]. However, I can now only perform this on one variable (var1). Do you know how to iterate this code over many variables in dataframe (from var1 to varn)? The code below is what I have done for one variable var1 in small example:

```
import pandas as pd
#Create dataframe
data = {'year': [1990,1990,1991,1991,1991],
        'var1': [10,20,45,40,55]}
df= pd.DataFrame(data)
obsperyearvar1 = df.groupby('year')['var1'].transform('size')
df['rankvar1'] = df.groupby('year')['var1'].rank().div(obsperyearvar1)
print(df)
   year  var1  rankvar1
0  1990    10  0.500000
1  1990    20  1.000000
2  1991    45  0.666667
3  1991    40  0.333333
4  1991    55  1.000000
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can try:

```
df = pd.concat([df, df.groupby('year').apply(pd.Series.rank, pct=True).filter(
    like='var'pct=True).add_prefix('rank')], axis=1axis =1)
```

Complete example:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create dataframe
data = {'year': [1990, 1990, 1991, 1991, 1991],
        'var1': [10, 20, 45, 40, 55],
        'var2': [10, 1, 5, 40, 5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df =  pd.concat([df, df.groupby('year').apply(pd.Series.rank, pct=True).filter(
    like='var'pct=True).add_prefix('rank')], axis=1axis =1)
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
   year  var1  var2  rankvar1  rankvar2
0  1990    10    10  0.500000       1.0
1  1990    20     1  1.000000       0.5
2  1991    45     5  0.666667       0.5
3  1991    40    40  0.333333       1.0
4  1991    55     5  1.000000       0.5
```

Comment: It does not work. It justs adds many replicated columns exactly the same as 'rankvar1' to the dataframe

Comment: @lindo I've added the complete working example. It's working

Comment: Sorry this one works. Thanks a lot! @Nk03

Answer (score 1):

Another option via [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas-dataframe-join) + [`groupby rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.rank.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-rank):

```
new_df = df.join(df.groupby('year').rank(pct=True).add_prefix('rank'))
```

`new_df`:

```
   year  var1  rankvar1
0  1990    10  0.500000
1  1990    20  1.000000
2  1991    45  0.666667
3  1991    40  0.333333
4  1991    55  1.000000
```

Sample Data Thanks to [@Nk03](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68033986/15497888):

```
import pandas as pd

# Create dataframe
data = {'year': [1990, 1990, 1991, 1991, 1991],
        'var1': [10, 20, 45, 40, 55],
        'var2': [10, 1, 5, 40, 5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

new_df = df.join(df.groupby('year').rank(pct=True).add_prefix('rank'))

print(new_df)
```

`new_df`:

```
   year  var1  var2  rankvar1  rankvar2
0  1990    10    10  0.500000       1.0
1  1990    20     1  1.000000       0.5
2  1991    45     5  0.666667       0.5
3  1991    40    40  0.333333       1.0
4  1991    55     5  1.000000       0.5
```

Comment: Thanks. This one is also perfect!